# how to filter Google Analytics 4 events based on more than one event params on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I export my Google Analytics 4 event data to Google BigQuery. I have table like this from this query

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as event_date_time,
  event_name,
  event_params,
  platform,
  user_pseudo_id,
  user_id,
FROM
  `xxxxxxx.analytics_296834888.events_intraday_20240118`
ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC
```

[image]

as you can see there are `page_location` and `medium` nested on `event_params` column.

I want to check every Google Analytics event that has `page_location = "https://myweb/"` and `medium = "organic"`

I can only filter page_location only like this:

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) as event_date_time,
  event_name,
  event_params,
  param,
  platform,
  user_pseudo_id,
  user_id,
FROM
  `blueray-cargo.analytics_296834888.events_*`,
UNNEST(event_params) AS param
WHERE event_name = "first_visit"
AND param.key = "page_location"
AND param.value.string_value = "https://myWeb.id//"
ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC
```

I can not filter `page_location` and also `medium`

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you should use CTEs to accomplish the task in 2 steps. Here's the adjusted query: The first query should extract page_location and medium from nested fields, and the second query should filter their values.

```
WITH preprocessed_events AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AS event_date_time,
    event_name,
    user_pseudo_id,
    user_id,
    platform,
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS page_location,
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'medium') AS medium
  FROM
    `blueray-cargo.analytics_296834888.events_*`
  WHERE
    event_name = "first_visit"
)

SELECT
  event_date_time,
  event_name,
  user_pseudo_id,
  user_id,
  platform
FROM
  preprocessed_events
WHERE
  page_location = "https://myWeb.id//" AND medium = "organic"
ORDER BY
  event_date_time DESC
```